# How to create a github release with an annotated tag?

Tags: version-control, github, tags

I've created a release on github, but it seems to be a non-annotated tag. Anyone know how to make an annotated tag along with a release? Is it OK to just replace the tag with an annotated one -- will it still work?

Comment: Found the answer to the second part of my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002555/can-a-lightweight-tag-be-converted-to-an-annotated-tag

Comment: I assume you would be able to create an annotated tag from the command line, and then push it (with `git push --tags`) to GitHub, where you could continue to edit it.

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy Yes, see the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Annotated tags are created using the `-a` flag.

The difference between regular tag to annotated tag is that the annotated tag is like a commit, it contain the date, author and the message attached to it.

Once you create the tags simply push it to the github repository
`git push --tags`. Since tags are simply a pointer to a given commit you can "move" them between commit.

#### Creating annotated tag

`git tag -a <tagname>`

#### Moving an existing tag

`git tag -a <tagname> <SHA-1> -f`

#### Pushing the tags

`git push origin --tags -f`

The important thing is the `-f` (force) flag

Comment: Don't forget the tagname ```git tag -a <tagname>```

Comment: This doesn't work for me - I pushed 2 annotated tags, but an older tag still shows up as "latest release" at https://github.com/:user/:repo/releases

Comment: I found out why - as well as pushing the tag, I need to use the Web UI to 'Draft a release' as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18512221