# Can an annotated tag be replaced with a lightweight tag?

Tags: git, git-tag

I run a private repository which uses lightweight tags, [as it allows for easy testing and review before going public](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4974420/3357935).

One of our tags was created with an incorrect name (`v0.21.` vs `v0.2.1`). Additionally, this tag was created as an annotated tag on accident. As such, editing the tag would modify its creation date, [making our GitHub releases display in a non-chronological order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738647/change-date-of-git-tag-or-github-release-based-on-it).

[I know it's possible to convert a lightweight tag to an annotated tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002555/can-a-lightweight-tag-be-converted-to-an-annotated-tag). Is it possible to do the reverse and downgrade an annotated tag to a lightweight tag?

Comment: A normal tag doesn't have it's own date, it "uses" the date of the commit it points to. It's just a label (like a branch) to a commit.

Comment: @MrTux That's only true for lightweight tags. [Annotated tags are unique objects with their own message, author, and creation date](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25996877/3357935).

Comment: The question was how to replace an annotated tag with a lightweight tag - thus my comment is true. Just delete it and create a new normal tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did, based on [MrTux's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3906760/mrtux):

##### List all the tags and their associated commits

```
git for-each-ref --sort -v:refname --format '%(objectname) %(objecttype) %(refname)
%(*objectname) %(*objecttype) %(*refname)' refs/tags
```

- If an entry looks like this, then it's an annotated tag:

  ```
  f844099a21d37a0139cbccd1f179113937d3fe69 tag refs/tags/v0.4.1
  1639e13f12fac2c36b7d50661589990355c03419 commit refs/tags/v0.4.1^{}
  ```
- If an entry looks like this, then it's a lightweight tag since there's no tag hash:

  ```
  644adce83cdd25057fa865701c509d852d5d44d5 commit refs/tags/v0.4.0
  refs/tags/v0.4.0^{}
  ```

##### To replace one annotated tag with a lightweight tag

(Using the example from above)

1. Delete the tag, e.g.

   ```
   git tag -d v0.4.1
   ```
2. Create a new tag

   ```
   git tag v0.4.1 1639e13f12fac2c36b7d50661589990355c03419
   ```

   - Make sure to use the commit hash of the original tag and not the tag hash
   - Make sure **not** to use `-a`, `-s`, or `-u` as these will create annotated tags

##### To replace all annotated tags with lightweight tags

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short) %(*objectname)" "refs/tags/*" | while IFS= read -r line; do tag=$(echo "$line" | cut -f 1 -d " "); hash=$(echo "$line" | cut -f 2 -d " "); git tag -d $tag && git tag $tag $hash; done
```